# Eclipse and Git - Repositories from GitHub not available from Import menu (Projects from Git are available)

Tags: java, eclipse, git, repository

I am trying to install doc4xj from Git per the instructions listed here --> http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/docx4j-from-github-in-eclipse/

I have installed Git in Eclipse (Kepler) from this update site:
http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

I am at the step where you select "Repositories from GitHub", but that option is not listed.  The only option I have is "Projects from Git".

I have installed version 3.5.2.201411120430-r. I have installed the following (everything available from http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates)

Eclipse Git Team Provider

- Eclipse Git Team Provider    3.5.2.201411120430-r
- Eclipse Git Team Provider - Source Code  3.5.2.201411120430-r
- Task focused interface for Eclipse Git Team   Provider   3.5.2.201411120430-r

JGit

- Co  JGit mmand Line Interface for Java implementation of
  Git  3.5.2.201411120430-r
- Command Line Interface for Java implementation of Git - Source
  Code 3.5.2.201411120430-r
- Java implementation of Git   3.5.2.201411120430-r
- Java implementation of Git - optional Http support using Apache
  httpclient   3.5.2.201411120430-r
- Java implementation of Git - optional Java 7
  libraries    3.5.2.201411120430-r
- Java implementation of Git - Source Code 3.5.2.201411120430-r

I have not used Git before so I could be doing something obviously wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Github integration is part of the GitHub Mylyn Connector which can be installed from [this](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates) update site but is not part of EGit itself. See http://eclipse.org/egit/download/ for a complete listing of all EGit related update sites.

Comment: Specifically, I had to install the GitHub MyLyn Connector. Thanks!